# Media modal in IE9 not working when included from plugin with wp admin scripts minified

Tags: media-modal

This issue occurs with custom code that uses the WP Media modal, such as https://github.com/humanmade/Custom-Meta-Boxes or https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/

The modal window does not load in IE9, except if I add `define('WP_SCRIPT_DEBUG', true)` so the wp admin scripts/styles are not minified.

Buttons with the "button" class don't get the styles applied for example, so I suppose that somehow the media upload modal styles aren't loaded either.

This happens only after version 4.0

[image]

Comment: admins/authors should not use IE, especially not IE9. There is simply no excuse to using outdated browser which no one tests against.

Comment: AFAIK WordPress hasn't dropped support for IE9 yet

Comment: since you are using plugins you are in unsupported area. It is just not smart to use fringe browser when there are mainstream alternatives

Comment: I've also encountered this issue. For me it occurs when using ACF image and file uploads. @MarkKaplun, your comment is so unhelpful, if you don't have anything to add, don't add anything.

Comment: @kdev, it is great to see that you follow your own advice.